# NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert gets called twice for 1 insert with different object IDs

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm losing my mind around this question.

So I have a Core Data setup in my iOS app done this way:
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

I then insert an object by creating a temporary MOC (as explained in the blog post) and perform saves on all 3 contexts in performBlock: methods.

In a view controller I have an `NSFetchedResultsController` and it gets notified that I did indeed insert a new object. The problem is that the `NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert` is fired twice and each time the object that is passed trough has a different `objectID` (it also is a different object instance in memory). What happens is that I then have 2 rows inserted in my table view but un the SQL database there is only one new. It then of course crashes when I scroll to the bottom of the table view.

If I also perform some updates on the object I get `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` called only once and with the objectID that was passed in the second `NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert` call.

The first ID looks like this:

> `<x-coredata:///ReceivedMessage/t605BB9A7-A04E-4B89-B568-65B12E8C259A2>`

The second (and all consequent ones) like this:

> `<x-coredata://02A917C5-850F-4C67-B8E4-1C5790CF3919/ReceivedMessage/p28>`

What could this be? Am I missing out something obvious?

PS: I also checked if the notification comes from the same context, thread, etc. It does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two IDs you are seeing may very well represent one object. The difference between them is just that the first one is a temporary object ID, assigned to the object on creation, and the second one is the permanent object ID, assigned to the object when it gets stored to the managed object store (see [NSManagedObjectID's isTemporaryID](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectID_Class/Reference/NSManagedObjectID.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSManagedObjectID)).

To work around this issue you could call [NSManagedObjectContext's obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html) just before you save the temporary MOC. This way the inserted object will have just one ID during the save propagation and the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods should get called just once.